# Automatic resolve dependency hierarchy for a custom jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I am struggling with the maven dependencies. The maven dependency hierarchy is not resolved in my projects where I add my custom build jar. This is a little bit confusing, because all the dependencies of other externally provided dependencies (like org.json, reasteasy-jaxrs ) are nicely shown in the dependency hierarchy view.I am using Eclipse EE IDE for Web Developers with maven plugin.

The project structure: The project is a platform consisting of several services using the same project-support module. Further, the project-support will be used in external projects (here project-consumer) as well.

- project-parent (pom)

  - *project-support* (jar)
  - project-service-a (war)
  - project-service-b (jar)
- project-consumer (war)

  - *project support* (jar)

**Extract of project-parent.pom**

```
<modules>
    <module>../project-support</module>
    <module>../project-serviceA</module>
    <module>../project-serviceB</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.50</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**Extract of project-support.pom**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.somecompany.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../project-parent</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>project-support</artifactId>
<name>projectsupport</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Extract of project-service-a.pom**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.somecompany.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-serviceA</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../project-parent</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>project-service-a</artifactId>
<name>projectsupport</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.somecompany.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So, when looking at the project-serviceA dependency hierarchy (and also in the effective pom), the required dependencies of project-support are not included which results in code compilation errors. Further the project-support is used in projects outside the scope of project-parent.

So my question: Why does maven not resolve the dependencies tree of project-support and adds them into the effective pom?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the *scope* of the dependencies to *provided* in you parent's dependency management section. According to the [introduction to the dependency mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), the dependency scope is used to limit the *transitivity* of a dependency.

The above linked introduction also includes a table that declares which scopes play in the transitivity game and which do not. The *provided* scope is not part of the transitivity.

So the solution is to not declare any scope in the dependency management but declare a reasonable scope in the dependency usage.

Comment: Thanks for the link, with that background, i finally managed to understand this. This might be impact our deployment strategy, ut the solution works. Thanks